# Can the disks need to be formatted before cStor pool creation?

Tags: openebs

I have few SSD disks attached to my nodes.Shall I wipe disks used before for OpenEBS when I reuse them ? So should I do a format of this disk is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to format the disks before providing the cStor pool. As part of the creation, it clears the disks and use the entire disk part of zfs pool.